# .NET Regex Add Character to End of Non-Blank Lines

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm working in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2013.  Trying to format a large string read from a file selected by the user.  I need to add a tilde ~ to the end of every line but only if that line is not blank.  Current code:

```
Dim finalstrANSItext As New List(Of String)
For Each strANSI As String In strArrANSItext
    strANSI = Regex.Replace(strANSI, "$", "~")
    finalstrANSItext.Add(strANSI)
Next
```

This adds the ~ to the end of EVERY line, including empty lines.

I tried this:

```
Dim finalstrANSItext As New List(Of String)
For Each strANSI As String In strArrANSItext
    strANSI = Regex.Replace(strANSI, "(.)$", "~")
    finalstrANSItext.Add(strANSI)
Next
```

This adds the ~ only to the end of non-blank lines, as I want, but it is also removing the last character of every line, which I do not want.

Regex is not my forte, as you can probably tell.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the replacement part you need to refer the captured group index(Group index 1).

```
strANSI = Regex.Replace(strANSI, "(.)$", "$1~")
```

**OR**

Use a lookbehind to match  end of the line  only if it's preceded by a character. Lookarounds are zero width assertions, it won't consume or match any characters.

```
strANSI = Regex.Replace(strANSI, "(?<=.)$", "~")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Both worked perfectly.  I'll accept your answer when it lets me in 9 minutes....